# Changing width of django filter form

Tags: python, django, django-filters

my filters.py file

```
import django_filters
from django_filters import CharFilter 
from .models import *
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput, Textarea
from django.forms import widgets

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name=CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains', label="", widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search Here'}))
    class Meta:
        model=Product
        fields='__all__'
        exclude=['name', 'price', 'digital', 'image', 'description']
```

How can I change width of the filter form to the size of search bar we have in stackoverflow for example?

A code snippet demonstrating it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked.

```
from django import forms

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name=CharFilter(field_name='name', lookup_expr='icontains', label="", widget=TextInput(attrs=
        {   'placeholder': 'Search for products, brands and more', 
            'class': 'form-control',
            'size': 100,
        }
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give the widget a class and set that class to say `width: 100%;` or however you'd like.

```
import django_filters
from django_filters import CharFilter 
from .models import *
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput, Textarea
from django.forms import widgets

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    search=CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label="", widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search Here', 'class': 'full-width'}))
    class Meta:
        model=Product
        fields='__all__'
        exclude=['name', 'price', 'digital', 'image', 'description']
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more as to how to do it?